When running in CMD, some environment variables are cleared, but the new program can still see them
Problems
Please check the following commands and their outputs!
D:\tmp>@echo off

REM command 1
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %f in ('set') do set %f=

REM command 2
set

REM command 3
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %f in ('set') do echo %f
COMSPEC
CONDA_BAT
CONDA_EXE
CONDA_SHLVL
PATH
PATHEXT
PROMPT


Command 1 is to unset all the variables
Command 2 is to show the variables, and indeed there's no output
Command 3 is to show the variables one by one, and indeed there're some variables

Notice:

the set command run in the sub-shell
if a batch file run, the environment variables can be seen.
When running on powershell, the environment variables are gone in the sub shell.





My Questions
How can I unset the above environment variables, in that the new program cannot see them?

The above document already includes my tries.
I also did on powershell, all the variables are gone in the new program.


Some built-in variables cannot be completely cleared.

@tripleee: That said, CONDA stuff is not built-in.

Are you actually using DOS (i.e. Microsoft DOS from the early 90s), or are you using a command prompt within Windows?

The execution of for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %f in ('set') do echo %f results in running in background %ComSpec% /c set. There is not used the option /D by cmd.exe on running one more cmd.exe in background. There is searched for that reason for the AutoRun registry value under key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor and on not existing here as by default next under key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor where is by Windows default also no AutoRun registry string value.

There is an AutoRun registry string value on your PC which runs most likely in the execution of a batch file which defines the CONDA environment variables. There can be executed C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun and the command line can be seen which is always executed by cmd.exe independent on which process runs cmd.exe without option /D. Run C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f for the deletion of this registry value.

Run in the command prompt window cmd /? for more information about the option /D and the AutoRun much too often used completely wrong for setting up a special environment which is in real set up whenever an executable calls the system function for the execution of a command by the Windows Command Processor in background via the environment variable ComSpec defined as system environment variable with %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe. The CONDA environment setup is therefore more or less malicious.

The AutoRun registry value should be used by a user only if the user wants a specific prompt and registers therefore the command prompt with an appropriate argument for the prompt definition. Every other command line registered as AutoRun command line is somehow malicious as thousands of applications use the system function most often without the application developer knowing how it really works. The entire registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor does not exist by default on Windows 11 but exists by default on former versions of Windows.

There should be run after the command line for deletion of the current user AutoRun registry value once again C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor". If there is nothing else output than the registry key, run C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /f for the deletion of the entire registry key. Otherwise keep the key. The registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor exists on all Windows by default with several registry values.

I recommend reading this answer which explains how to create a shortcut file stored on the user's desktop or in the user's start menu or pinned on the Windows taskbar for opening a command prompt window by executing %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe with the options /D and /K and execution of the batch file which sets up the Anaconda or CONDA environment only for this running instance of the Command Processor needed for development in the Anaconda environment by the user.

Dear Mofi:  If I start cmd through "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /D",  the issue is still there.  It seems option '/D' doesn't work,  or I got something wrong. If option '/D' really doesn't work, I have to unregister the key.

@VicZhang You can start %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe with usage of option /D to ignore the AutoRun command line. But when you now run for /F "delims==" %i in ('set') do set %i= to delete all local environment variables and run next for /F "delims=" %i in ('set') do @echo %i there is executed twice in background C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c set. Both temporarily started cmd.exe are run without option /D and execute for that reason first the AutoRun command line before running the command set specified as argument on the command line after option /c.

@VicZhang There is no possibility to prevent the execution of the registered AutoRun command line on using for /F for execution of a command line and capture its standard output for further processing. A user cannot control how the system function calls the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess for running the Windows Command Processor for the execution of a command line. That is the reason why an AutoRun registry value is nearly always bad. It affects lots of apps.

@VicZhang It is not even possible to use set ComSpec=%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D before first usage of the environment variable ComSpec by cmd.exe (see Information about environment variable ComSpec in my answer on How do I loop over the output of pushd in Windows Command Processor?) as the system function passes the entire string value of ComSpec to CreateProcess as function parameter lpApplicationName resulting in the attempt to execute the program with the file name C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe \D which cannot be found.

@VicZhang Read the Microsoft documentation about Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces why the option /D in the "file name string" becomes \D. The AutoRun registry value should be used on any PC with Windows only with command prompt to change the prompt. Every other registered AutoRun command line cause troubles and should be removed for that reason. All pages suggesting registration of AutoRun for setting up a special environment on user opening a command prompt window don't know how harmful it is doing that.

@Mofi, thanks a lot. And I learned a lot from answers!

The reason for the observed behavior is that what you are nunning from the for command is executed in a separate cmd instance.
When you run the first set command in a new instance and retrieve the variables in this instance, you see all the default variables by system configuration, and any inherited variable from the current instance, and clean them.
Then, in the second command, you see that the current instance does not have any variable.
But when you run the third command, the set is executed again in a new instance and you see all the default variables defined by system configuration on the start of a new cmd instance.

That is right and wrong at the same time. There is indeed executed in background %ComSpec% /c set. But there are on Windows 11 23H2 only three environment variables set by the Windows Command Processor itself: COMSPEC, PATHEXT and PROMPT Read the chapter Information about environment variable ComSpec in my answer on How do I loop over the output of pushd in Windows Command Processor? for the reason why the environment variable COMSPEC is still defined.

The Windows Command Processor cmd.exe defines PATHEXT and PROMPT by itself on not being defined anymore. That is a special fallback. PowerShell has built-in no fallback for PATHEXT.

@mofi, how is it wrong? The answer indicates defined by system configuration. Does it not include the variables in the autorun section?

The answer is right if you mean with defined by system configuration the entire operating system configuration including the AutoRun registry values of the Command Processor registry keys. The answer is partly wrong if you mean with this phrase just the system environment variables as it can be seen on clicking on Start button, typing on keyboard environment, clicking on suggested item Edit the system environment variables, clicking on button Environment Variables… and looking on the System variables. These variables do not matter here in this special case.

The last sentence is incorrect: "…, the set is executed again in a new instance and you see all the default variables defined by system configuration on the start of a new cmd instance." There is indeed started a new instance of cmd.exe because of cmd.exe running as command prompt calls via system function the kernel function CreateProcess for execution of %ComSpec% /c set.

But the function parameter lpEnvironment is a null pointer resulting in new cmd instance gets copied by CreateProcess the current empty list of environment variables of running cmd.exe. The persistent stored environment variables in registry are not read by system or CreateProcess or new instance of cmd.exe. That is the reason why without AutoRun registry value as by Windows default there are defined in memory of new cmd.exe instance only COMSPEC, PATHEXT and PROMPT and none of the system and user environment variables including PATH.
